# Using SWT broswer widget to open a .pdf file in IE

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying open a .pdf file using swt browser widget in IE using the following code-

```
    _browser.setUrl(
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("UserGuide00.pdf")
    .toAbsolutePath().toString());
    return _browser;
```

The problem is that the pdf file is getting launched as a separate document and not within the browser. what am i missing? Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
browser.setText("<html>\r\n" + "<body>\r\n" + "<embed\r\n"
                    + " type=\"application/pdf\"\r\n"
                    + " src=\"file:/C:/Users/tom/Documents/myPDF.pdf\"\r\n"
                    + " id=\"pdfDocument\"\r\n" + " width=\"300\"\r\n"
                    + " height=\"300\">\r\n" + "</embed>\r\n" + "</body>\r\n"
                    + "</html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The API says `browser.setUrl()` therefore, the input parameter to the method should conform to the proper url syntax. Following works with SUN JDK_1.6.x and latest eclipse release (3.7.2).

```
File file = new File("c:/temp/test.pdf");
try {
    browser.setUrl(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: whats your OS, default browser on that OS, JDK version, adobe reader version and eclipse distribution? The solution i posted used win7, adobe reader 10.x, jdk_1.6, ie8 as default browser for SWT and eclipse 3.7.2. On a windows system it is possible that your adobe reader is an older version.